# Database select statement, trying to use wildcards to display specific rows

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to select all airlines where has the value **'Air Canada Rouge'** for example, in the Airline columns there is sometimes concatenated values such as **Air Canada, Air Canada Rouge, Air Transat**. An example of the select statement I am currently using is:

```
select * from crs where Airline LIKE '%airlineName' OR Airline LIKE
'airlineName,%' OR Airline LIKE ',airlineName%';
```

This only works for rows that have Airlines that include 2 values such as **Air Canada, Air Canada Rouge**.

But I need the select statement to fetch rows with columns that has values that include 3 or 4 concatenated airlines.

How would I make a select statement to do this?

Thank you

Comment: As you want an exact match `where ',' + airline + ',' like '%,airlineName,%'` - But you should normalize the data to one-item-per-row then this becomes trivial, in most cases delimited data in a column is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
select * 
from crs 
where Airline LIKE '%airlineName%';
```